# MySQL Ver 15.1 doesn't partition table

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, partitioning

I'm trying to create a table that will have partition by range of years using phpmyadmin in a server with:

```
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.60-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

(using `mysql -V` in Centos 7)

The code I use to create is:

```
CREATE TABLE `datosenfermedades` (
  `clues` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `unidadmedica` varchar(75) NOT NULL,
  `fechaconsulta` datetime NOT NULL,
  `idconsulta` int(15) NOT NULL,
  `clavediagnostico` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `primeravez` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `clavemunicipio` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `edad` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `sexo` varchar(1) NOT NULL,
  `grupoedad` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `derechohabiencia` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `servicio` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `nivelatencion` int(1) NOT NULL
) 
PARTITION BY RANGE (year(fechaconsulta)) (
  PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2008) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2009) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2010) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (2011) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (2012) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (2013) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (2014) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN (2015) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN (2016) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p9 VALUES LESS THAN (2017) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p10 VALUES LESS THAN (2018) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p11 VALUES LESS THAN (2019) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p12 VALUES LESS THAN (2020) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p13 VALUES LESS THAN (2021) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p14 VALUES LESS THAN (2022) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p15 VALUES LESS THAN (2023) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p16 VALUES LESS THAN (2024) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p17 VALUES LESS THAN (2025) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p18 VALUES LESS THAN (2026) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p19 VALUES LESS THAN (2027) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p20 VALUES LESS THAN (2028) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p21 VALUES LESS THAN (2029) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p22 VALUES LESS THAN (2030) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p23 VALUES LESS THAN (2031) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p24 VALUES LESS THAN (2032) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p25 VALUES LESS THAN (2033) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p26 VALUES LESS THAN (2034) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p27 VALUES LESS THAN (2035) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p28 VALUES LESS THAN (2036) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p29 VALUES LESS THAN (2037) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p30 VALUES LESS THAN (2038) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p31 VALUES LESS THAN (2039) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p32 VALUES LESS THAN (2040) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p33 VALUES LESS THAN (2041) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p34 VALUES LESS THAN (2042) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p35 VALUES LESS THAN (2043) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p36 VALUES LESS THAN (2044) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p37 VALUES LESS THAN (2045) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p38 VALUES LESS THAN (2046) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p39 VALUES LESS THAN (2047) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p40 VALUES LESS THAN (2048) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p41 VALUES LESS THAN (2049) ENGINE=MyISAM,
  PARTITION p42 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE=MyISAM
);
```

The table apparently is correctly created and when I use the commando `SHOW CREATE TABLE datosenfermedades` I get:

```
CREATE TABLE `datosenfermedades` (
     `clues` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
     `unidadmedica` varchar(75) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
     `fechaconsulta` datetime NOT NULL,
     `idconsulta` int(15) NOT NULL,
     `clavediagnostico` varchar(6) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
     `primeravez` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
     `clavemunicipio` int(3) NOT NULL,
     `edad` int(3) NOT NULL,
     `sexo` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
     `grupoedad` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
     `derechohabiencia` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
     `servicio` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci NOT NULL,
     `nivelatencion` int(1) NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci
    /*!50100 PARTITION BY RANGE (year(fechaconsulta))
    (PARTITION p0 VALUES LESS THAN (2008) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN (2009) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN (2010) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p3 VALUES LESS THAN (2011) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p4 VALUES LESS THAN (2012) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p5 VALUES LESS THAN (2013) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p6 VALUES LESS THAN (2014) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p7 VALUES LESS THAN (2015) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p8 VALUES LESS THAN (2016) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p9 VALUES LESS THAN (2017) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p10 VALUES LESS THAN (2018) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p11 VALUES LESS THAN (2019) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p12 VALUES LESS THAN (2020) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p13 VALUES LESS THAN (2021) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p14 VALUES LESS THAN (2022) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p15 VALUES LESS THAN (2023) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p16 VALUES LESS THAN (2024) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p17 VALUES LESS THAN (2025) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p18 VALUES LESS THAN (2026) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p19 VALUES LESS THAN (2027) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p20 VALUES LESS THAN (2028) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p21 VALUES LESS THAN (2029) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p22 VALUES LESS THAN (2030) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p23 VALUES LESS THAN (2031) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p24 VALUES LESS THAN (2032) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p25 VALUES LESS THAN (2033) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p26 VALUES LESS THAN (2034) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p27 VALUES LESS THAN (2035) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p28 VALUES LESS THAN (2036) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p29 VALUES LESS THAN (2037) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p30 VALUES LESS THAN (2038) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p31 VALUES LESS THAN (2039) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p32 VALUES LESS THAN (2040) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p33 VALUES LESS THAN (2041) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p34 VALUES LESS THAN (2042) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p35 VALUES LESS THAN (2043) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p36 VALUES LESS THAN (2044) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p37 VALUES LESS THAN (2045) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p38 VALUES LESS THAN (2046) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p39 VALUES LESS THAN (2047) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p40 VALUES LESS THAN (2048) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p41 VALUES LESS THAN (2049) ENGINE = MyISAM,
    PARTITION p42 VALUES LESS THAN MAXVALUE ENGINE = MyISAM) */
```

If I'm correct mysql just comment my partitions instructions. After all I insert 3,142,157 values on the table from 2007 to 2017 and when I try to use the commando "`SELECT * FROM datosenfermedades PARTITION (p1)`" I get the next error:

```
    You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(p1)
LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1
```

Comment: Creating partitions seems to have worked, but partition selection (=defining the partition to use in a query) requires at least MySQL 5.6, so you cannot use this feature in your MySQL 5.5.60.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is almost no reason to use "partition selection".  You should let the engine do the work of figuring out which partition (or partitions) to look in to satisfy the query.

These days, you should abandon MyISAM and move to InnoDB.

`int(3)` is a 4-byte number.  The `(3)` means nothing.  Look up `TINYINT`.

There are no indexes on this table?  Use indexes for performance, not partitioning.

If you had `INDEX(fechaconsulta)`, this would fetch the same rows:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    WHERE fechaconsulta >= '2009-01-01'
      AND fechaconsulta  < '2009-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR;
```

And it would do it efficiently with or without partitioning.